# Cannot use `open` command via SSH on Mac

Tags: ssh, mac

I have a workflow where I use SSH in terminal in conjunction with remote desktop, and I often use the `open` command in SSH to open something in the GUI.

However, recently it stopped working with the following failure:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1
$ open .
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-600 "procNotFound: no eligible process with specified descriptor" UserInfo={_LSLine=387, _LSFunction=_LSAnnotateAndSendAppleEventWithOptions}
```

Just running `open .` locally on the machine works fine, it opens finder at the current working directory. It also seems to have started happening recently in Mac OS Monterey, but I wasn't able to track down exactly on which version it stopped working.

Any ideas what is causing this or how it can be worked around?

Comment: Have you Google searched some of those errors?  I looked up one, and got this thread, which simply says to reboot. I assume you tried it, but worth mentioning. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653027